# Alternative to mcdropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu, autocomplete

I'm building an autocomplete dropdown list where the user can pick from categories in several levels.

On the previous version of the site, we used http://www.givainc.com/labs/mcdropdown_jquery_plugin.htm for this which worked fine. However it doesn't seem to support higher versions of jQuery. I tried hacking the lib, removing and replacing some features which sorta worked, but introduced new issues.

I'm wondering if there are any good alternatives out there (I've looked but haven't found anything so far) or how one would go about building a hierarchical dropdown like this?

Answer (score 1):

How about [Select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/)? It's different visually, but I think that the search functionality is faster than clicking around. It also displays subcategories in a vertical format.

Answer (score 1):

a couple of other alternatives:

jQuery menu - http://jqueryui.com/menu/

chosen.js   - http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/

I think both support some kind of hierachy.

Answer (score 0):

mcDropdown is multi-level drop-down list. So, I believe the best alternative is [ComboTree](http://www.jeasyui.com/documentation/combotree.php) plugin in [EasyUI](http://www.jeasyui.com/index.php)

> The combotree combines the selection control with drop-down tree. It is
>   similar to combobox but replace the list with tree component.

You can also add auto-complete feature on it by some modifications. 
see: [ComboTree - AutoComplete](http://www.jeasyui.com/forum/index.php?topic=1964.0)