# jQuery select widget with nested selectable optgroups

Tags: jquery

I am looking for jQuery select (drop-down list) widget with multi-level selectable optgroups support. for example contatins the following items:

```
- sel_1
- sel_2
  - sel_2_1
  - sel 2_2
- sel_3
  - sel_3_1
  - sel_3_2
    - sel_3_2_1
    - sel_3_2_2
      - sel_3_2_2_1
      - sel_3_2_2_2
  - sel_3_3
    - sel_3_3_1
    - sel_3_3_2
- sel_4
```

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11168257/multiple-level-select-in-html

Comment: The most similar project to my requirement is mcDropdown. However, it seems out of date and is not supported anymore. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17147967/alternative-to-mcdropdown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the multi-level select plugin. [ComboTree](http://www.jeasyui.com/documentation/combotree.php) in [EasyUI](http://www.jeasyui.com/) jQuery plugins is the best choice for my application.

> The combotree combines the selection control with drop-down tree. It
>   is similar to combobox but replace the list with tree component.